Made for TV series on counter intelligence and CIA during cold war
I have watched this series/movie (I think netflix) but can't remember the name after trying so hard.
The story spans during and after cold war era. It's about 2 friends; who join CIA, and the lead character ultimately rises to a top post in counter intelligence after an accident where he loses full use of one leg.
Towards the very end he realizes his long time friend is the mole the whole CIA has been looking for for so long.
I can't remember the name of the made for tv movie/series and it's bothering me.
It was a very well made series and I had really liked it.
Any body who can suggest me some names I can look up.

This sounds like The Company (2007), a 3-part miniseries.  According to Wikipedia,

The Company is an American fiction miniseries that follows the Cold War intelligence battle between the CIA and the KGB from the end of World War II to the fall of the Soviet Union. The protagonist is Jack McAuliffe (Chris O'Donnell), an idealistic and naive "true believer" who was recruited from Yale by his crew coach. Starts in 1955, then flashes to 1950, then ends in 1991. In all it spans 41 years.

The Wikipedia synopsis doesn't mention a crippling accident, but Jack's best friend, Leo Kritzky, does indeed turn out to be working for the KGB.

thanks so much. this is the one I have been looking for. How did you find this so quickly :-)

@Ayusman:  You're welcome!  I used an IMDb keyword search for "mole" and "CIA".  There were just six matches.
